# Change color multiple marker in google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to ask about how to change color of a marker in google maps. The condition is, I have a program to create multiple markers in google maps. But how I can give specified color to each marker?

this is my code for now,

```html
var markers = [];
var map;
var labels = 'ABCD';
var labelIndex = 0;

function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
  label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
  icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
 map: map
   });
  markers.push(marker);
```

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to pass the color into the `addMarker` function:

```
function addMarker(location, color) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/'+color+'.png',
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfsn4akh/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var markers = [];
var map;
var labels = 'ABCD';
var labelIndex = 0;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // New York, NY, USA (40.7127837, -74.0059413)
  // Newark, NJ, USA (40.735657, -74.1723667)
  // Jersey City, NJ, USA (40.72815749999999, -74.07764170000002)
  // Bayonne, NJ, USA (40.6687141, -74.11430910000001)

  addMarker({
    lat: 40.7127837,
    lng: -74.0059413
  }, "red");
  addMarker({
    lat: 40.735657,
    lng: -74.1723667
  }, "green");
  addMarker({
    lat: 40.7281575,
    lng: -74.0776417
  }, "yellow");
  addMarker({
    lat: 40.6687141,
    lng: -74.1143091
  }, "orange");
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


function addMarker(location, color) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
    icon: {
      url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/' + color + '.png',
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(15, 10)
    },
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```