# Ionic/Cordova Google Maps app crash after add two marker with different icons

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i need your help please, i'm building android application
i use Cordova google maps plugins with ionic v 1.3
all work fine
if i add two marker one with icon and other without or with the same icone is work good  
the problem is when i add two markers with different icons 
application crash without any error 

this is my code :

```
 //create marker of begin and arrive
    map.clear();
    map.addMarker({
      position: depart,
      title: "Vous êtes ici.",
      //snippet: "description",
      icon: {
        url: "www/images/depart.png"
      },
      animation: plugin.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });
    map.addMarker({
      position: arriver,
      title: "L'arrivée.",
      //snippet: "description",
      icon: {
        url: "www/images/arrive.png"
      },
      animation: plugin.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    });
```

thanks

My logcat errors log :

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(11620): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
E/AndroidRuntime(11620): Process: com.ionicframework.myApp468132, PID: 11620
E/AndroidRuntime(11620): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at maps.w.d.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at maps.y.F.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at maps.ad.S.b(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at aep.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:169)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzf$zza$zza.setVisible(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.setVisible(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at plugin.google.maps.PluginMarker$1.onPostExecute(PluginMarker.java:164)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at plugin.google.maps.PluginMarker$7.doInBackground(PluginMarker.java:743)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at plugin.google.maps.PluginMarker$7.doInBackground(PluginMarker.java:698)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(11620):        ... 4 more
```

Comment: can you post your logcat error log?

Comment: try changing your approach. add locations to array, then in for loop add markers. like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example

Comment: i'm actually curious, please post a working example if you manage to fix it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805138/change-color-multiple-marker-in-google-maps-api

Comment: @Marko thanks but this is not working
if you use color or icon from url is work fine but when i use two files application crash

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira i add my logcat errors log to my question thank you alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using this plugin with ionic 2 and getting same issue, but after digging  plugin's java code i tried as following :

1. I kept my icon inside icon directory (eg: src/assets/icon/myicon1.png).
2. Then i used during adding location marker as following :

   icon : './assets/icon/myicon1.png'

   icon : './assets/icon/myicon2.png'

Now its working fine.