# multiple marker by condition in map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initMap() {
        var map;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var mapOptions = {
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };

        // Display a map on the page
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);

        var markers = [];
        var infoWindowContent = [];

        <?php   
        $query = "select id, dealer, lat, lon, dtype from dealer_m_testing where status = '1' and deleted is NULL"; 
        $query .= " order by seq asc";
        $dealers = mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_num_rows($dealers) > 0){
          $i=0;
          while($dealer = mysql_fetch_array($dealers)){ ?>
            var marker = [];
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['id']; ?>');
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['dealer']; ?>');
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['lat']; ?>');
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['lon']; ?>');
            marker.push('<?php echo $dealer['dtype']; ?>');
            markers.push(marker);
            <?php
          }
        } ?>

        // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
        for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
          var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3], markers[i][4]);
          bounds.extend(position);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            id: markers[i][0],
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][1],
            if (markers[i][4]=='P')
                    icon: 'https://trivenialmirah.com/img/red.png';
            else if (markers[i][4]=='R')
                    icon: 'https://trivenialmirah.com/img/blue.png';
            }
          });

          // Allow each marker to have an info window    
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                showDetails(marker.id);
            }
          })(marker, i));

          // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
          map.fitBounds(bounds);

        }

        // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
          //this.setZoom(1);
          google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });

      }

    </script>
```

Comment: Please expand on your question. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to make two different color pin on Map screen with the condition,
If my "dtype" value is 'P' then Red color Pin and else if "dtype" value is 'R' then Blue color Pin publish on my website Dealer map screen.

So Please help me for this script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color multiple marker in google maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805138/change-color-multiple-marker-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: Please refer this anser may be it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805138/change-color-multiple-marker-in-google-maps-api?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: both links are not sufficient for my requirement coz our data amount is minimum 600 Dealers.
Please take a look this link https://www.trivenialmirah.com/dealers_map.php
for check my functionality of Pins

Comment: So Please advise me for, How to call data from Database with condition and publish by Pin on Map Screen according to that Condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have these images `https://trivenialmirah.com/img/red.png` saved in your application, what you can do is rename them based on the value of `dtype` that is pushed to your markers array.

```
https://trivenialmirah.com/img/P.png
https://trivenialmirah.com/img/R.png
```

that way you can now do something similar to this

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  id: markers[i][0],
  position: position,
  map: map,
  title: markers[i][1],
  icon: `https://trivenialmirah.com/img/${markers[i][4]}.png`;   
});
```

Comment: Sorry Sir,
When i put this code in my page then upload on server and see that Map screen not showing. Please see this link for the same. https://trivenialmirah.com/dm1.php

Comment: Sir I'm very tensed with this work, and no solution can be found.

Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Now It has been Done by your reference.
and so I'm very Happy and Thanks a lot for help me.

Comment: Great! its good to know it works